# How to insert or update if a condition is true, but not at every row?

Tags: php, mysql

When I search for a word in the searching box, if the word is not in my database I want to add him for giving suggestions, and if the word is already in the database I just want to update the number of searches of that word to can make a top of most popular words.

It's like Google. The search box works but I don't know how to insert the word just one time not every time the rows are fetched.

```
$cuvant=$_GET['cuvant']; //the word that I introduce in the searching box
$sql="SELECT * from cautare";// cautare is the table where I keep the words
$resursa=mysql_query($sql); //the resource
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resursa)) {
        $nr=$row['nr_cautari'];//number of serching of each word
        if ($row['cuvant']!=$cuvant && $cuvant!=''){//if the word is not in the database i want to insert him 
            $nr=1;
            $sql2="INSERT INTO cautare values('".$cuvant."',".$nr.")";
            $resursa2=mysql_query($sql2);
        }else if($row['cuvant']==$cuvant && $cuvant!=''){ //if the word is in the database i just want to uptdate the number_of_searches field
            $nr=$nr+1;
            $sql3="UPDATE cautare set nr_cautari=".$nr."where cuvant='".$cuvant."'";//update the number_of_searches field
            $resursa3=mysql_query($sql3);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `UNIQUE` key on the word field, and then:

```
INSERT INTO table (...)
  VALUES (...)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field=field+1
```